# Pull Values from compactRio with Python

Tags: labview

I have a compactRio system that I've inherited but don't know much about (I have no background with LabView).  All I really need to do is poll the values from some of the probes attached to the the cRio every few minutes over the network interface.

Currently, I have a Python script that grabs hourly summary files of the collected data via FTP.  However those files are only updated by the cRio on an hourly basis and I need data more frequently than that.

Do cRios commonly have SNMP/console/etc interfaces available over TCP/UDP that I could poll to get this data on a remote machine?  Any suggestions for the optimal way to do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to poll the cRIO without modifying the LabVIEW program.

If you do decide to have a go at LabVIEW programming, I suggest setting up a RESTful API. Since you are already accessing the cRIO over FTP, I am assuming you can access it via HTTP calls with python curl. Here is a quick tutorial on how to setup a [RESTful API in LabVIEW 2013](http://chrislarson.me/blog/labview-web-services-restful-crud) or for [LabVIEW 2012 and earlier](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361G-01/lvhowto/build_web_service/)

Comment: Thanks Chris, a RESTful API would work great as I have plenty of experience with those.  I'll look into that.